# A PowerShell Script to install fonts on Windows 11

Tags: powershell, installation, fonts, powershell-3.0

I would like help with the following ps script that I took from reddit to install fonts for all Windows 11 users, below is the original script:

```
#set font source location

$FontFolder = "FONT LOCATION"

$FontItem = Get-Item -Path $FontFolder

#go through all folders in source and list all fon, otf, ttc and ttf files

$FontList = Get-ChildItem -Path "$FontItem\*" -Include ('*.fon','*.otf','*.ttc','*.ttf') -Recurse

foreach ($Font in $FontList) {

Write-Host 'Installing font -' $Font.BaseName

Copy-Item $Font "C:\Windows\Fonts"

#register font for all users

New-ItemProperty -Name $Font.BaseName -Path "HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts" -PropertyType string -Value $Font.name

}
```

In the original script I need to set the full path of the folder where the fonts are, and if I copy this folder to another drive I have to update the path before running it, but what I need and want is for it to recognize the folder where it is being executed without me having to set the path, as happens with a batch script that starts with the command cd /d "%~dp0", like the one below that I use to install the Notepad++:

```
mode con lines=30 cols=70
@ECHO off
cd /d "%~dp0"
cd /d "%~dp0" && ( if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ) && fsutil dirty query %systemdrive% 1>nul 2>nul || (  echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) : UAC.ShellExecute "cmd.exe", "/k cd ""%~sdp0"" && %~s0 %params%", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" && exit /B )
cls
echo.
@echo  ßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßß
@echo   ßß                                                              ßß
@echo    ßß           S O F T E H A R D    S O L U T I O N S           ßß
@echo     ßß                                                          ßß
@echo      ßß       ßßßß    ßßßß     ßß  ßß      ßßßßßß  ßßßßßß      ßß
@echo       ßß     ßß  ßß  ßß  ßß    ßß  ßßß     ßß      ßß  ßß     ßß
@echo        ßß    ßß      ßß        ßß  ßß ßß   ßß      ßß  ßß    ßß
@echo         ßß   ßßßß    ßßßß      ßß  ßß  ßß  ßßßßßß  ßß  ßß   ßß
@echo         ßß     ßßßß    ßßßß    ßß  ßß  ßß  ßß      ßß  ßß   ßß
@echo        ßß        ßß      ßß    ßß  ßß  ßß  ßß      ßß  ßß    ßß
@echo       ßß     ßß  ßß  ßß  ßß    ßß  ßß  ßß  ßß      ßß  ßß     ßß
@echo      ßß       ßßßß    ßßßß     ßß  ßß  ßß  ßß      ßßßßßß      ßß
@echo     ßß                                                          ßß
@echo    ßß                    I N F O R M A T I C A                   ßß
@echo   ßß                                                              ßß
@echo  ßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßßß
@CHCP 1252 >NUL                                                            
@Title Silent installation of Notepad++ software version 64-bit..          
echo.                                                                      
echo.         We are starting the silent installation of the software      
echo.                                                                      
echo.                          "Notepad++ 64-bit"                          
echo.                                                                      
echo.                   When the installation is complete                  
echo.             this message will disappear and the application          
echo.             will start so you can configure it before using it.      
echo.                                                                      
@echo OFF
FOR %%i IN ("npp*.exe") DO Set FileName="%%i"
%FileName% /S
echo. Installation completed successfully - Starting Notepad Plus Plus 64-bit!
@Start explorer.exe "%ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Notepad++.lnk"
timeout /t 4
exit
```

I search for the equivalent "cd /d "%~dp0"" command and I just found this "$PSScriptRoot", did anyone knows if this will solve my problem?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Best Regards

Comment: Is there a reason you can't try it yourself to see if it solves your problem? It's clear your computer and keyboard both work, and you know how to use them both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly stated the variable $PSScriptRoot is exactly what you need

```
$FontList = Get-ChildItem -Path $PSScriptRoot -Include ('*.fon','*.otf','*.ttc','*.ttf') -Recurse
```

Beaware that the variable $PSScriptRoot is not populated in the following scenarios:

- You use your statement in PowerShell ISE console
- You use your statement in PowerShell console without a script file
- You marked only this expression for execution in PowerShell ISE